# difference between (>>=) and (>=>)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I need some clarification regarding (>>=) and (>=>).

```
*Main Control.Monad> :type (>>=)                                                                                                                                                               
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b                                                                                                                                                
*Main Control.Monad> :type (>=>)                                                                                                                                                               
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
```

I know about bind operator(>>=) but I am not getting the context where (>=>) is useful. Please explain with simple toy example.

Edit : Correcting based on @Thomas comments

Comment: Where did you find that one is a lazy version of the other?  We should correct or remove this resource as it is wrong.

Comment: `f >=> g = \x -> f x >>= g`

Comment: Hi Thomas, 

please look this frame https://youtu.be/2jdJGdA7AYs?t=3m30s

Comment: @Thomas these things used in the same context in this video but I didn't understand explanation, so I am posting here

Comment: @venugangireddy That video is talking about lazy IO and when actions are taken (such as reading a file, computing values, and closing handles).  The interesting thing in the video is not the operators you are focused on but `print` happening within the scope of `withFile` vs afterwards.

Comment: The lazyness-difference between `withX (h >=> p)` and `withX h >>= p` in some application has nothing to do with the difference between `>=>` and `>>=`. It's the same way `fmap g $!! fmap f $ x` and `fmap (g . f) $!! x` are different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `(>=>)` function is kind of like `(.)`, but instead of working with `a -> b`, it works with `a -> m b`.

```
-- Ask the user a question, get an answer.
promptUser :: String -> IO String
promptUser s = putStrLn s >> getLine

-- note: readFile :: String -> IO String

-- Ask the user which file to read, return the file contents.
readPromptedFile :: String -> IO String
readPromptedFile = promptUser >=> readFile

-- Ask the user which file to read,
-- then print the contents to standard output
main = readPromptedFile "Read which file?" >>= putStr
```

This is a bit contrived but it illustrates `(>=>)`.  Like `(.)`, you don't *need* it, but it is generally useful for writing programs in the point-free style.

Note that `(.)` has the opposite argument order from `(>=>)`, but there is also `(<=<)` which is `flip (>=>)`.

```
readPromptedFile = readFile <=< promptUser
```

Comment: Thanks Dietrich, Is there any name for this operator?

Comment: The informal name is the fish operator; formally, it is the left-to-right Kleisli composition operator. (Functions of the form `a -> m b` are called Kleisli arrows, a concept from category theory.)